# Region of continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity

Describe the region where the function $f(x,y)=\cos^{-1}(xy)$ is continuous.

I have done the following:

The range of $\cos$ is $[-1,1]$, therefore the domain of $\cos^{-1}(xy)$ is $[-1,1]$.

The domain of $\cos$ is $\mathbb{R}$, therefore the range of $\cos^{-1}(xy)$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Are the points of discontinuity/singular points the ones that don't belong to the domain?

We have that $\nabla f=(0,0)\Rightarrow \left (-\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2y^2}}, -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2y^2}}\right )=(0,0)\Rightarrow (x,y)=(0,0)$.

So is the extremum of the function at the point $(0,0)$ ?

The Hessian matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{xy^3}{(1-x^2y^2)^{3/2}} & -\frac{1}{(1-x^2y^2)^{3/2}} \\ -\frac{1}{(1-x^2y^2)^{3/2}} & -\frac{x^3y}{(1-x^2y^2)^{3/2}}\end{pmatrix}$. Do we have to fnd the eigenvalus to check where the function is convex and where concave?

For the asymptotes we have to calculate the limits as $x\rightarrow \infty$, $y\rightarrow \infty$, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range of $\cos$ is $[-1,1]$ and therefore the domain of $\arccos$ is $[-1,1]$. So, the domain of $\arccos(xy)$ is $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid xy\in[-1,1]\}$. And, since $\arccos$ and $(x,y)\mapsto xy$ are continuous, your function is continuous too.

Comment: So do we just check the domain? Do we not need the other information (range, points of discontinuity, asymptotes, etc) ?

Comment: In this case in which we are dealing two continuous functions, no, nothing alse is needed. And, in fact, I only mentioned the domain to correct your wrong assertion that the domain of $\arccos(xy)$ is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: So is the region of continuity of the function $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid xy\in[-1,1]\}$ ?

Comment: Yes- Asserting that a function is continuous is the same thing as asserting that its region of continuity is its domain.

Comment: Ok! So when we have for example the function $f(x,y)=\ln (x-3y)$, it must hold $x-3y>0 \Rightarrow x>3y$. Therefore the domain is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x>3y\}$. And, since $\ln$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x-3y$ are continuous, the function $f$ is continuous too. And so the region of continuity of the function is $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid x>3y\}$. Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: That's just fine!

Comment: Great!! I have also an other question. To draw with Geogebra the region where the functions are continuous do we do that for example like that: https://ibb.co/94TLZrz ? Or is there a specific command in Geogebra that we have to use?

Comment: The region where the function is continuous is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$. That link shows us that, but it also shows us the graph of the function, which is not relevant here.

Comment: So you mean that I have to draw only the region $x>3y$ and not the function itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105570/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-mary-star).